How do I get a raw input device's proper display name in C#?
I am making a simple program to enumerate all of the devices currently connected to your Windows along with their pointers, then display the proper name for the device you clicked a button on your WPF window in C#.
I have finished writing the code to collect all the devices input using
NativeMethods.GetRawInputDeviceList(pRawInputDeviceList, ref deviceCount, (uint)dwSize);

for (var i = 0; i < deviceCount; i++)
{
   var rid = (RawInputDeviceList)Marshal.PtrToStructure(new IntPtr((pRawInputDeviceList.ToInt64() + (dwSize * i))), typeof(RawInputDeviceList));
}

and now all I need is to just get the product name for the device, aka something like TUF GAMING M5 in case of my mouse, which is how it shows up in my Device Manager window.
It appears as though using
NativeMethods.GetRawInputDeviceInfo(hDevice, RawInputDeviceInfo.RIDI_DEVICENAME, IntPtr.Zero, ref pcbSize);
gets me the device path and not something actually meant to be read by a human. I've seen people mention BOOLEAN HidD_GetProductString(in]  HANDLE HidDeviceObject,  [out] PVOID  Buffer,  [in]  ULONG  BufferLength);
but everytime it's mentioned, people say it only seems to work for HID devices and not mouses or keyboards. Even if I did decide to use it, I don't know how to get the appropriate BufferLength for it with nothing but a raw input device struct.
If anyone is able to help me with this, I would strong appreciate it.

It's a lot better to use WMI for this, eg var searcher== new ManagementObjectSearcher(        "SELECT * FROM Win32_SoundDevice");

use wmi for what? getting the product name or something else in the code?

All of the information. Device Manager, Powershell and monitoring/management tools use WMI to get that information even from remote computers, not Win32 API calls. Mice are in the Win32_PointingDevice class

Can i get an example of how i would go about enumerating all connected devices; keyboards, mice, hids, usb and bluetooth with that? I've seen people mention wmi before but i couldn't really find any useful links so i didn't know how to go about it

couldn't really find any useful links there are thousands of links and articles going back decades, precisely because it's so fundamental to administration. WMI itself is thoroughly documented, and so is ManagementObjectSearcher. I found out about Win32_SoundDevice by googling for WMI input device and finding this probably duplicate SO question. Sound is input too. And USB devices are not necessarily input. A lot of devices are connected to the USB bus directly, especially on laptops.

If you check the link to Win32_PointingDevice I posted you'll see it's a doc page in Computer System Hardware Classes reference. USB and Bluetooth aren't devices, it's how devices connect to the computer. Bluetooth itself is a networking device. You can search all devices by querying the Win32_PnPDevices class

Also check this Powershell article that shows how to query for wireless mice and keyboard. You can use Powershell commands to explore devices and their attributes to find which ones interest you before writing a WMI query.

Ensure that you dispose of any object that has a Dispose method. The easiest way to do this is to use a using statement. See the following post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73780436/10024425.  Also see Win32 Provider and Computer System Hardware Classes

In PowerShell, you can try the following which allows you to write a query similar to the one in C#: Get-CimInstance -Namespace Root\Cimv2 -Query "Select * From Win32_PointingDevice" | Format-list -Property *

The common way is to use WMI, not Win32 API calls. That's what system and monitoring tools as well, to list and control devices on the local machine or any machine on a company's network.
You can query the Win32_KeyboardDevice and Win32_PointingDevice classes to find keyboards and mice or other pointing devices, or query their parent CIM_UserDevice
var searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("root\\CIMV2",
             "SELECT * FROM CIM_UserDevice");

foreach (var queryObj in searcher.Get())
{
    Console.WriteLine("Class: {0}\tName {1}", 
                      queryObj["CreationClassName"],
                      queryObj["Name"]);
}

Talking about "input devices" in general is ambiguous. After all, sound devices are input devices while USB and Bluetooth is how devices connect to the machine. Mice are shown in the Win32_PointingDevice class, keyboards in the Win32_Keyboard class. Both of them have CIM_UserDevice as a parent class
The article Use PowerShell and WMI to Find Wireless Keyboard & Mouse shows how to easily list entries in a class using the Get-WMIObject command, or gwmi for short.
Running
gwmi -class Win32_PointingDevice

Lists all pointing devices and shows that the objects are derived from CIM_UserDevice among others
__DERIVATION  : {CIM_PointingDevice, CIM_UserDevice, CIM_LogicalDevice, CIM_LogicalElement...}

Querying CIM_UserDevice and listing just the class and name with :
gwmi -class CIM_UserDevice |Format-Table CreationClassName,Name,Caption

Returns
CreationClassName    Name                                                         Caption
-----------------    ----                                                         -------
Win32_DesktopMonitor Wide viewing angle & High density FlexView Display 3840x2160 Wide viewing angle & High density FlexView Display 3840x2160
Win32_Keyboard       Enhanced (101- or 102-key)                                   Enhanced (101- or 102-key)
Win32_Keyboard       Enhanced (101- or 102-key)                                   Enhanced (101- or 102-key)
Win32_Keyboard       Enhanced (101- or 102-key)                                   Enhanced (101- or 102-key)
Win32_PointingDevice USB Input Device                                             USB Input Device
Win32_PointingDevice HID-compliant mouse                                          HID-compliant mouse
Win32_PointingDevice Synaptics Pointing Device                                    Synaptics Pointing Device
Win32_PointingDevice USB Input Device                                             USB Input Device
Win32_PointingDevice HID-compliant mouse                                          HID-compliant mouse

The equivalent in C# is :
var searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("root\\CIMV2",
             "SELECT * FROM CIM_UserDevice");

foreach (ManagementObject queryObj in searcher.Get())
{
    Console.WriteLine("Class: {0}\tName {1}", queryObj["CreationClassName"],queryObj["Name"]);
}


Thank you! I really appreciate you going through all the trouble of typing this whole thing out for me. It's a little embarrassing but I'm TERRIBLE at looking up things on google since i can spend hours at a time just trying to figure out the correct term for the word query or something, so I usually prefer asking things directly on forums like that. Having a good solid foundation for figuring out how to go about this is exactly what I needed!

Sorry to bother you with this again, but how would I get a pointer to the raw input device out of these wmi classes? Since the code i'm working on is meant to detect raw input using wm_input, i store all of the devices' pointers to differentiate between them on wm_input system message using lparam. Win32_pointingdevice doesn't seen to have any pointers that I could use to tell if that's the device used by wm_input
